# Delete de registros duplicados

Tags: mysql, delete

Tenho uma base onde os existem registros no o número identificador duplicado, em alguns cenários a data do registro mais novo se difere da do antigo, porém o número e o mesmo (Tenho que apagar o registro com a data menor) em outros casos as datas e números do identificador são iguais (Tenho que manter apenas um registro). Estou usando os dados abaixo, mas não estão sendo apagado os registros duplicados.

Deletes:

1 - Se eu uso esse apaga todos os registros.

```
DELETE RES1 FROM REGISTRO AS RES1, REGISTRO AS RES2 WHERE RES1.HR_TRA <= RES2.HR_TRA AND RES1.NUMERO = RES2.NUMERO 
AND RES1.DT_DATA <= RES2.DT_DATA;
```

2 - Caso use esse, matem registros duplicados.

```
DELETE RES1 FROM REGISTRO AS RES1, REGISTRO AS RES2 WHERE RES1.HR_TRA < RES2.HR_TRA AND RES1.NUMERO = RES2.NUMERO 
AND RES1.DT_DATA <= RES2.DT_DATA;
```

Criação e população da base:

```
-- CRIANDO BASE DE TESTE REGISTROS DUPLICADOS

CREATE DATABASE TESTE;
USE TESTE;
CREATE TABLE REGISTRO 
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NUMERO INT(10),
NOME VARCHAR(20),
VALOR INT(10),
DATA_ATU DATETIME,
HR_TRA TIME,
DT_DATA DATE
);

INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('2','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 17:06:06', '17:06:06', '2020/02/04');
INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('2','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 17:06:06', '17:06:06', '2020/02/04');
INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('2','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 16:06:06', '16:06:06', '2020/02/04');
INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('2','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 15:06:06', '15:06:06', '2020/02/04');
INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('2','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 15:06:06', '15:06:06', '2020/02/04');
INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('1','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 15:06:06', '15:06:06', '2020/02/04');
INSERT INTO REGISTRO (NUMERO, NOME, VALOR, DATA_ATU, HR_TRA, DT_DATA) VALUES ('3','TESTE', '200', '2020/02/04 15:06:06', '15:06:06', '2020/02/04');
```

Comment: Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: Acredito que tenha entendido o que vc precisa, você precisara de apoio de um cursor do mysql ou de uma linguagem para fazer um laço nos registros duplicados. Apenas com o comando delete não sei se da para fazer o que precisa.

Comment: Creio que também deve funcionar, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este comando parece fazer o que você quer:

```
delete res1 from REGISTRO res1
inner join REGISTRO res2
where res1.numero = res2.numero and 
   (res1.dt_data < res2.dt_data or 
        (res1.dt_data = res2.dt_data and 
         res1.id < res2.id)
    );
```

O truque foi usar a coluna "id" além da coluna "dt_data". Quando duas linhas tiverem a mesma data, então escolhemos o id menor para apagar.

Comment: Efetuei o teste aqui, super funcionou. Obrigado!!

Comment: Blz, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como a correta, que me rende uns pontinhos :D

Comment: Pronto, marcado como certo!